# Internal CSS works, but external doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, styles

**Internal CSS works, but external doesn't. I've tried the external with the code !important, but it just didn't made any sense.**
I want to add a gallery to my site. But I have a problem. As I've seen in the browser some margin overwrites the ext. CSS. But here's the thing, I have no margins in the HTML code. The only thing I can imagine is that the Bootstrap is doing something with high priority.

```css
div.gallery {
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 180px;
    position: static;
}
      
div.gallery:hover {
    border: 1px solid #777;
}
      
div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
      
div.desc {
    padding: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lZN37f5QGtY3VHgisS14W3ExzMWZxybE1SJSEsQp9S+oqd12jhcu+A56Ebc1zFSJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
      
   <div class="gallery">
       <a target="_blank" href="gtrr35.jpg">
          <img src="gtrr35.jpg" alt="Nissan GT-R R35 Nismo">
       </a>
       <div class="desc">Nissan GT-R R35 Nismo</div>        
   </div>
```

Comment: Where is the carsale css located on the disk? Is it in the same folder as the html?

Comment: Yes, I have everything in the same folder.

Comment: can you be more specific? your code runs okay on codepen

Comment: OMG... You're right, I was using VS Code until now, it ruined my day and this isn't the first time when something just doesn't want to work in that app.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your custom css stylesheet linked?
It should be the last of all the other  tags (fromm top-left to bottom -right),  otherwise it gets overwritten due the cascading aspect of CSS...

Comment: Yes, I know that. The custom stylesheet is the last.